# AngularJs invoke a function in form sending

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form with upload file functionality. The upload functionality already removed, and the idea is to upload the picture on backend along with other form data.

```
var uploaderImages = $scope.uploaderImages = new FileUploader({
        url: '/api/productimg'
      });

$scope.addProducts = function(){
       ProductApi.addProduct($scope.product)
         .then(function(response){  -----> form data has been saved!!
                    uploaderImages() ----> invoke this cause an error
             })
             .catch(function(response){
                 console.log(response.data);  
             })

    }
```

Thanks!!

Comment: `----> invoke this cause an error` -- What error? Please provide a little bit more details.

Comment: @Michael `TypeError: uploaderImages is not a function`

Comment: @Michael same stuff `TypeError: $scope.uploaderImages is not a function`

Comment: don't expect a useful answer if you just provide minimum information! What is `FileUploader`? From which library? Are you sure you use it the correct way? Did you read the documentation of FileUploader?

Comment: @Michael It's based on angular-file-upload. It works fine if I attach `ng-click="uploaderImages.uploadAll()"` on a button. But I don't want user able to upload a picture without saving a form data. Everything is works fine. The issue is how can I invoke the `FileUploader` within the `addProducts` function. SO the form will be saved first follow by file uploads.

Comment: Why do you use `uploaderImages()` instead of `uploaderImages.uploadAll()` in your code????

Comment: @Michael that's how the sample code works. You can upload single file, or multiple file.

Comment: maybe you use the wrong version or didn't read the documentation. According the doc on https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API you should probalby use `uploaderImages.uploadItem()`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var uploaderImages = $scope.uploaderImages = new FileUploader({
  url: '/api/productimg'
});
```

`uploaderImages` is an object. You can't call it like a function. See the documentation of `FileUploader` to find the adequate method to call.

Comment: I can call `uploaderImages.uploadAll()` with a button, no doc on how I can trigger this call within a function